# Unable to restart apache, when trying to set up ssl for amazon linux 2 (ec2 instance)

Tags: apache-httpd, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up ssl on amazon linux 2, and am unable to restart apache

COMMAND :

`sudo systemctl restart httpd`

Error:

`Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

When I run `journalctl -xe` , I get this:

```
Aug 26 18:10:01 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Aug 26 18:10:09 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16302]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/pki/tls/certs
Aug 26 18:10:09 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16302]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for useAug 26 18:10:09 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16302]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for useAug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16307]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/pki/tls/certs
Aug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16307]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for useAug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exitedAug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Aug 26 18:10:18 ip-something.ap-south-1.compute.internal sudo[16307]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for use-bash
```

When I run , `sudo apachectl configtest`, I get:

```
Syntax OK
```

How do I solve this, thank you

PS : I am very new to linux, so I am sorry, if the error is very obvious... thanks again

Comment: Apache also produces its own logs, usually under /var/log/apache2 or similar. You will probably get more info on the failure in them. That's if you have access to them.

Comment: I tried to go to that file, but it  seems such a file or directory doesnt exist

Comment: Check the location in the config files, and/or start it up manually in the foreground.

Comment: ok so I manually opened the file directory, and it turns out /var/log exists, but there is no apache or apche2 after them, i could only find /amazon and /audit